# Android MVVM App Architecture: How to set up FirebaseFirestore as Repository

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm

I want to create a app with the [new architecture components](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/arch/) and i already set up the views and the ViewModel. At the moment my app performs all Firestore queries in the ViewModel and it works to some extent. [Google recommends](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#common_architectural_principles) that you should provide a Repository that caches some data and decides whether to fetch new data. This makes perfectly sense for my application since a have several Fragments nested in my MainActivity and lots of other activites.

I decided to implement the repository and created a Kotlin Object (Singleton) for my repository. As a consequence i got the warning that i should not store a FirebaseFirestore instance in it because it contains a Context field (i need an instance to assign snapshotListeners).

```
Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)
```

**I completely understand this warning** but i wonder **how i should implement the Repository pattern with Firebase in my app without being in danger of causing a memory leak**? Since Firebase and the new Architecure Components/Guidlines are both from Google i assume there are designed to work together but after doing some research i wasn't able to figure it out.

Does anyone know an effective way to implement a repository with Firebase snapshotListeners?

Comment: Have you got answer for this? any references?

Comment: @ShivarajPatil I have answered the question from experience I have gained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question. Meanwhile, I have found a great way to solve this problem. The best way is to make use of the repository pattern and Dependency Injection.
That means you have a class with a private field `firebaseFirestore` that implements an interface that defines all database operations (`RemoteRepository` in my case).
The class itself is provided as a Singelton via Dependency Injection.

```
class FirebaseRepository : RemoteRepository {
   private val firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

   override suspend fun saveSomething(...) {
     ...
   }

   override suspend fun getSomething(id: String) : T {
     return ...
   }


}
```